# New windows in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

Is there any way to control where and at what size new windows open under windows 10 (at least in common Microsoft Office products)?

I work in a Windows/Word/Outlook office environment and recently was upgraded to a modern large, landscape mode monitor (from a smaller square one).  I have found it irritating for windows to open in a seemingly disorganized manner, but usually in the center of the screen at inconvenient sizes.  I would like to be able to set generally at what size and where they open.

I have been using windows key-arrow to set windows after they are open to take up a vertical half screen, but wonder if there are other, more granular controls I can set or use.

Comment: Generally applications tend to store information such as window positions this when they exit on a per-user basis and therefore under HKCU.  For example, a quick look in the registry for Word 2016 I assume this is relevant: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options\
AppWindowPos  Some applications store the values in a more friendly way but in general you can usually set the keys before launching the application but I'm surprised it's not remembering.  Process Monitor https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procmon is a helpful tool for understanding such settings.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Unfortunately, that link doesn't seem to be working.  Also, a clarification: my biggest discomfort is not with the apps themselves, but with additional windows opened by the app (e.g. a new doc in word; an email opened in outlook) etc.